# Writing a crontab job that references a properties file

Tags: properties, cron, ubuntu-server

I am running Ubuntu Server 12.04. I am trying to set up a cron job to run every week. If I were to write this command in the command prompt, it would look like this:
    name@computer:~/./runReport.sh weekly_ecc_name.properties

It works when run at command like the above

Now this is what I have for the cron job:
    * * * * * /runReport.sh weekly_ecc_name.properties > errors.txt 2>&1

I'm having it run every minute until I get it working.

The error that it spits out is Error: Could not find or load main class blarg (which refers to the file that reads the properties file).

I am not quite sure how to write this so that it works. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Solved it, Created a new .sh file and put the script in that file.

Changed the crontab to refer to that script so it ended up looking like this

* * * * * cd /home/user/reportfolder && sh newCommand.sh

It works like a charm.

Comment: Add this comment as an answer so that it will be useful to others.